# how to convert a text file of JSON to JSON array in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm a bit stumped on how to convert a text file of JSON to JSON array in Python?

So I have a text file that is constantly being written to with JSON entries, however the text file does not have bracket to call it as a JSON Array.

```
{"apple": "2", "orange": "3"}, {"apple": "5", "orange": "6"}, {"apple": "9", "orange": "10"} ...
```

How can I put that into a JSON array? My end goal is read the latest entry every time there is a new entry added. The JSON file is created by some other program that I have no control over, and its being written to constantly, so I can't just slap brackets to the start and end of the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read in the file, you can treat it as a string, to which you add brackets to. Then, pass that to the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to decode it as JSON for you.

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as f:
    raw_data = f.read().splitlines()[-1]
    list_data = f'[{raw_data}]'
    json_data = json.loads(list_data)
    print(json_data)

# [{'apple': '2', 'orange': '3'}, {'apple': '5', 'orange': '6'}, {'apple': '9', 'orange': '10'}]
```

This assumes that each line of the file should become a new array. The code extracts the last line of the file and converts it.